# Make a function has higher precedence than another

Tags: c++, function, c++11, ambiguous

So I have a function:

```
void foo(char a = 'A', int b = 0)
{
    // code
}
```

And I have another one:

```
void foo(int b = 0, char a = 'A')
{
    //code
}
```

Then if I call `foo()`, it will return an error because the compiler can't decide which function to call. So can I make a function that has higher precedence than another? So if I call `foo()` then the compiler which one to choose?

Comment: If you make one of them higher priority, then the other one could never be called, could it?  So why would you define the second one at all?

Comment: @NateEldredge: I assume they mean they just want a tie-breaker when either function is equally viable (thanks to being called with no arguments), but when called with arguments, it would select the more appropriate function.

Comment: @NateEldredge The second one has the variables swapped.

Comment: Why did you introduce the tie (by allowing either version to be called with no arguments)? The situation is a bit odd since *you* introduced the ambiguity, and instead of removing the ambiguity, you want to add something more.

Comment: Use explicit overloads instead of default parameters.  E.g. a foo(int b) which will call foo(char a, int b) with default a as 'A'. This will make it a lot easier to be explicit(!) about what you mean in your code and which function you want to have selected (by some very well defined rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use function overloading here:

```cpp
void foo(char a, int b = 0)
{
    // code
}

void foo(int b, char a = 'A')
{
    //code
}

void foo()
{
    foo(0); // Or 'foo('A');', depends on which overload you want to give priority
}
```

**Edit**: Or you could just remove the first default argument from one of the overloads:

```cpp
// Makes the compiler select the first overload when doing 'foo()'
void foo(char a = 'A', int b = 0)
{
    // code
}

void foo(int b, char a = 'A')
{
    //code
}
```

Or:

```cpp
// Makes the compiler select the second overload when doing 'foo()'
void foo(char a, int b = 0)
{
    // code
}

void foo(int b = 0, char a = 'A')
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Ah, should've thought of that as another option. Has the downside of not scaling as well if there are many combinations of defaulted arguments to be used (e.g. in this case, with just two arguments, you'd still need to put defaults for the second argument, or you wouldn't be able to call it with a single argument like you could with the OP's functions, and with more arguments, especially if several share a type for the first argument, you'd have to write a lot of shorter prototype overloads, not just the empty overload), but it avoids the waste of passing the defaults from every call site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to apply an implicit preference for one function or the other if both are found to be equally viable during [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

If you're stuck in this situation, the best you could do would be to wrap both functions in separate namespaces so you could choose which one to access through namespace qualified references. Other parts of the code could still bring both into their own lookup realm for unqualified use with `using` statements, and as long as the calls were unambiguous, they could be used unqualified in that way, with the programmer falling back to explicit namespace qualification when there is no way to resolve the ambiguity.